# React global state via props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, global-state

Im using a shared global state as the following:

```
interface DashboardProps extends React.Props<Dashboard> {
    globalState? : GlobalState
}

export class Dashboard extends React.Component<DashboardProps, any>{

}
```

In `AppLayout` i call it:

```
<Route  path='/dashboard'>
   <Dashboard globalState={this.state} />
</Route>
```

let say that inside `Dashboard` class I need to change the `globalState`, whats the best way to do so?

Thanks

Comment: The better way to do that is using redux. This [example](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html) is great to start learning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props are readonly (see docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only)). So, you either:

1. implement globalstate as a state in your `Dashboard` component, then pass down the handler to children of Dashboard so that they can change `globalState`. For example:

```js
// dashboard component
class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      globalState = /* some initial value */
    }
  }

  // handler to change globalState.
  globalStateHandler = (data) => {
    // perhaps some processing...
    this.setState({ 
      globalState: data,
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return <ChildComponentOne>
      <ChildComponentTwo>
        <SomeComponentOne globalStateHandler={this.globalStateHandler}/>
        <SomeComponentOne globalStateHandler={this.globalStateHandler}/>
      </ChildComponentTwo>
    </ChildComponentOne>
  }

}
```

2. Use a state management library like [redux](http://redux.js.org/), or [flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/). Using these libraries, you can keep the entire state of your apps and make them accessible in any of your components. This is probably the best option and many people have use these libraries to manage the state of their apps.
3. You could store globalState in `localStorage` or `window` global variable. Probably not a good idea, but possible nonetheless.